# Autogenerated column in sharepoint List

Tags: list

I have a list with a column by name S.No 
I need to autogenerate this column with this format 1000,1001,1002 etc

ex:
item 1=1000
item 2=1001
item 3=1003
any one assist me its urgent

Answer (score 1):

your question is confusing?

I think what you mean is:

You have a list, the list has a column. Within this column you want to auto generate a unique number when an item is added with the format of:

item 1=1000 item 2=1001 item 3=1002 ...

**solution:**

you need to do this through code, in visual studios create an event receiver for the list,

there are two methods, one is to get the current item id and -1 to get the value. Once you have the value you can then amend the list item to add that number.

second method is to get the list, get the total number of items within the list and -1 will give you the total number you need to add to that column.

this code will need to go into the item added event, as it can be added after the event of the item being occurred so it will make it easy for you!

solution 1 get the id from the item, id is a hidden property that Is ootb:

```
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdded(properties);
       SPItem item = properties.ListItem;

       int IDNum = item["ID"] - 1;
       IDNum = IDNum + 1000;

       item["S.No"] = IDNum 
       item.Update();
   }
```

solution 2 get total items to make id:

```
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdded(properties);
       SPList list = properties.ListItem.ParentList;

       int IDNum = list.ItemCount() -1;
       IDNum = IDNum + 1000;

       item["S.No"] = IDNum 
       item.Update();
   }
```

both methods should work, both methods are getting the last unique id, both should start at 1 because your using the method item added event so there is at least one item in the list with the id of 1, -1 will give you 0 and then you add 1000 to the value gives 1000 :) , so the last thing is to add that value into the column S.No!

some code might be wrong, its late and I'm going bed but that's pretty much the solution ;) , otherwise create a calculated column based on the ID column.... only issue is ID column needs to be visible on the list for it to work as its read only and is flaky when it comes to the first item (id is null rather than 0) so fails, but any item would work on calculated column as long as there is one item within the list for it to work correctly.

Comment: EDIT: Didn't read everything, but the calculated column formula would be: =([ID]-1)+1000 :)

Comment: thanks @AndersAune couldn't be arsed to work it out even though its simple as you put it ;) ! but as I noted that id column needs to be visible for it to work and also needs at least one record for it to work. but iv given you +1 as its correct :)